# Java Collection value locator

Tags: java, collections

i'm currently creating a GUI that uses the list collection. My problem is with the validation function.

```
public void idValidate(int id) {
    for (Item i : items) {
        if (i.getId() == id) {
            checker = true;
        } else {
            checker = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a sample of where I use this function.

```
private void checkEditBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int id = Integer.parseInt(idEditTxt.getText());
    idValidate(id);
    System.out.println(checker);
    if (checker == true) {
        nameEditTxt.setEditable(true);
        priceEditTxt.setEditable(true);
        descEditTxt.setEditable(true);
        updateEditBtn.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myJFrame.this, "ID not found!", "Validation Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

When I input 2 or more lists, the only ones that return true are the recently added ones. The checker does not return true if I try to locate the first item I input.

Thank you :)

Comment: If someone could explain what's wrong along with the downvotes, that would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where using a debugger is helpful.  You would be able to see that when you do `checker = false` this overwrites the existing value so it doesn't matter how many times you call `checker = true;` if you call `checker = false;` after it, this is the value you have.

Most likely you expected that once you set true, this is the value you want to keep.  In fact there is no point continuing in the loop, it's not going to get any true-r

Also it is better to return a result than set a mutable field.  This minimises the number of side effects of the method and makes it easier to reason about. i.e. minimises bugs.

```
public boolean idValidate(int id) {
    for (Item i : items) 
        if (i.getId() == id) 
            return true; // stop as soon as one is true.
    return false;
}
```

BTW In Java 8 you can write

```
public boolean idValidate(int id) {
    return items.stream().anyMatch(i -> i.getId() == id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit yuor as below:

```
public void idValidate(int id) {
    for (Item i : items) {
        if (i.getId() == id) { // if found then break the loop
            checker = true;
            break; // here
        } else {
            checker = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Once it was fund `break` the loop, otherwise the `checker` value again become `false`

**But is better to the code like this:**

```
public boolean idValidate(int id) {
        for (Item i : items) {
            if (i.getId() == id) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Then use like this:**

```
boolean isValid = idValidate(id);
if(isValid) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Note: if there is no items, the last value of `checker` is left.

Comment: I know understand the downvotes. That was so noob-ish of me. Thank you :)